# Django rest framework update Put not allowed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to update an object of my database (but only one of the field), the problem is that when I try to make the update i get an error that says that the PUT method is not allowed.

Here's my View:

```
class DeviceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    Show, create and filter devices.
    """
    queryset = Device.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        devices = Device.objects.filter(user=request.user.pk, role='E')
        serializer = DeviceSerializer(devices, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {
            'registration_id': request.data['regId'], 'user': request.user.pk, 'device_id': request.data['imei'],
            'type': 'android', 'label': request.data['label'], 'role': request.data['role']
        }
        serializer = DeviceSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            device = Device.objects.filter(device_id=request.data['imei'])
            device.send_message("Enhorabuena!", "El dispositivo se ha registrado correctamente.")
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         device = Device.objects.filter(device_id=request.data['imei'])
         device.registration_id = request.data['regId']
         device.save()
         serializer = DeviceSerializer(device)
        return Response({'ok': 'oks'})
```

My serializer:

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = '__all__'
```

My url:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

from decaught import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^devices/$', views.DeviceViewSet),

]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

I'm using Postman to send a PUT Request:

[image]

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: The error is in our URL. You need to select some ``device`` to PUT information. Try with ``localhost:8000/devices/1/``. I'm assuming that your API take objects by pk

Answer (score 3):

When `PUT`ting the resource identifier should be in the URL (pk). PUT request is *idempotent*. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT

In the DRF documentation, pk is passed as an argument to the update method

```
def update(self, request, pk=None):
    pass
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions

Instead of passing it as a key:value pair and accessing it through `request.data` PUT call should be like

```
localhost:8000/devices/<PK-HERE>/
```

(sorry for not so good english)

Answer (score 1):

The error is in our URL. You need to select some `device` to PUT information. Try with `localhost:8000/devices/1/`. I'm assuming that your API take objects by pk